# c++ function parameter char pointer and string

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing

```
void callme(string a)
{
  cout<<"STRING CALLED"<<endl;
}

void callme(char * a)
{
  cout<<"char pointer called"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
   callme("ASDADS");
   return 0;
}
```

why is it that the `char*` will be called? and why when I comment out the function with the `char*` parameter, the other function will be called instead?

Comment: (There's a help button in the editor. Read that. For code, select your code block and click on the `{}` button or hit Ctrl+K.)

Answer (score 4):

That's because `"ASDADS"` is convertible to `char *`. The compiler thus generates code for the first function it can match the argument to.

If you remove the prototype with `char *`, the compiler will look for functions that accept a parameter with an implicit cast from `char *` to the parameter type.

Take the following for example:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    A(int x) {}
};

//void foo(int x) {}
void foo(A x) {}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int x = 3;
    foo(x);
}
```

if you comment out `foo(int x)`, the other function will be called.

However, if you declare the constructor as `explicit`, you'll get an error:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    explicit A(int x) {}
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The type of a string literal (like `"abc"`) is "array of const char". However, as a special rule, C++ allows a (deprecated!) standard conversion to `char *`. Such a conversion is preferred over the user-defined conversion furnished by the constructor `string::string(const char *)`. Thus the `char*` overload wins during overload resolution (zero user-defined conversions for `char*` as opposed to one user-defined conversion for `string`).

(I can't actually find a standard reference for this; on the contrary, C.1.1 says explicitly that `char * p = "abc";` is "invalid in C++". Any further input is appreciated. *Edit:* It seems like this is a change from C++03 to C++11, and in C++11 this is indeed flat-out illegal.)

Comment: I think it's a compiler extension. I never really quite got it though, why you're allowed to have `char* = "foo";`, but run into UB when you try to change it. Why not just mandate it to be `const char*`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Well, even with `-pedantic` on GCC it says "deprecated conversion", so it doesn't sound like it's an extension...

Comment: I was talking about MSVS2008. I don't even get a warning.

Answer (score 0):

When you have both functions there are two alternatives to pick from and (char *) fits better to your argument "ASDADS". If you remove the (char *) function then there is a single function that wants a string. So the compiler creates a string using a string constructor that takes a char *.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/

Answer (score 0):

By default "ASDADS" is referenced by a char pointer. So 2nd version of callme() is used. If that is commented, compiler will try to match it with string and hence 1st version of callme() is used.